# Как изменить textView у child, android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Есть expandablelist view с чекбоксами. У каждого потомка есть textView. Когда я чекаю потомка, мне необходимо сменить textView у другого потомка. Как это можно сделать? Как обратиться?

Answer (score 1):

Решение ваших проблем, это переопределение [адаптера](http://www.startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html). В методе **getView()** вы можете задать обработчик, который будет проверять изменение для конкретного элемента, а далее вы можете написать функцию, которая при вызове обработчика будет изменять все другие View как вам угодно, для этого вы можете изменить переданные данные в адаптер, и вызвать метод **notifydatasetchanged()**

Comment: а как именно сделать, чтобы это было для конкретного элемента?

Comment: @userpixel как я уже писал выше вы передаёте какой-то массив в адаптер, просто изменить данные в нужном индексе и далее вызывайте метод ,который я писал выше